# extract images from pdf with php

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing

I'm trying to extract images from PDF with PHP.

I have succeeded partially - I have a gray scale image...

[image: gray scale image from pdf]

...and I know that I have to apply a formula on it to get colors!

But first, I need to convert binary data of the image to numbers, and then apply the formula from [the Adobe PDF specs](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

So basically, suppose you have the attached image (with all of the data from the PDF, no modification) and it's

```
1. CYMK image
2. 8 bit for each component
```

and you need to convert it to a colored image with PHP using attached the Adobe spec, under the "Image" section.

What can I do to solve that?

Comment: How did you extract the image, can you show some code or describe the method you used? Maybe it's just a small tweak that is necessary

Comment: i have used this class and did a modification for it  http://code.google.com/p/lucene-silverstripe-plugin/source/browse/trunk/thirdparty/class.pdf2text.php?r=19

Answer (score 3):

#### You can use [pdfimages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html).

The package gets installed when you install `xpdf`. The manpage describes:

> Pdfimages saves images from a Portable Document Format  (PDF)  file  as Portable Pixmap (PPM), Portable Bitmap (PBM), or JPEG files.
>
> Pdfimages  reads  the  PDF file, scans one or more pages, PDF-file, and writes one PPM, PBM, or JPEG file for each  image,  image-root-nnn.xxx, where  nnn  is  the image number and xxx is the image type (.ppm, .pbm, .jpg).
>
> NB: pdfimages extracts the raw image data from the  PDF  file,  without performing  any  additional  transforms.  Any rotation, clipping, color inversion, etc. done by the PDF content stream is ignored.

Comment: Apparently Load_image do the opposite of what iam asking here http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-load-image.php it puts image to pdf

Comment: Dear @Praveen Kumar , i have extracted the image , what i need exactly how can i did what adobe mentioned at their specs. to color this image in php

Comment: You can use something like `php_gd`

Answer (score 1):

The image you are showing is not grayscale, it is just inverted. Try to invert color bytes and you'll end up with good colors. There is a fuss about CMYK color storage in JPEG images caused by  Photoshop storing 100% colors as 0x0.

edit : how to invert in PHP, taken from [this blogpost](http://hanswestman.se/2011/07/some-image-filters-for-php-gd/) It is working on rgb data and must be adapted to work with CMYK

```
<?php
function image_filter_invert(&$image){
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);
    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++){
        for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++){
            $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
            $r = 0xFF-(($rgb>>16)&0xFF);
            $g = 0xFF-(($rgb>>8)&0xFF);
            $b = 0xFF-($rgb&0xFF);
            $color = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);
            imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, $color);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I edited the answer with a possible solution using PHP GD. Note that doing the transform from jpeg to jpeg will make you loose a little quality as you are recompressing the image data using a lossy codec

Comment: i have tried it but with no luck , also i got an other solution but all it did it makes my image white but with no colors !

Comment: Try to store the image as CMYK Tiff file if you can (without JPEG compression), that should do it.

Comment: nice but now iam using an other code and this did great till now except with CYMK image some colors disappear from image !!
Other code is here
http://phparadise.de/php-code/image-editing/invert-image/

Comment: This other code is working on RGB data (ie 3 bytes colors), you're missing a byte in the process.It should be simple to extend it to work on 4 bytes colors like CMYK.

Comment: best thing is to give example iam digging hard till now with no result's so point me :D

Comment: I'll try to make something as soon as i got some time, later today maybe. Seems that PHP GD is not a good lib for CMYK images though.